# JQuery loading content in a div

Tags: jquery

I am having difficulties with loading an html using JQuery. The following [example](http://jsfiddle.net/PLuyu/2/) was borrowed from another posting. I was unable to get this working in Chrome. Could someone please help me to tidy the code so that it is optimized for all browsers? Thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#selectchoice").change(function () {

        var selectedOption = $('#selectchoice :selected').val();
        $containerDiv = $('#get_content');
        $containerDiv.html("");
        switch (selectedOption) {
            case "1":
                $containerDiv.html("http://www.google.com/index.html");
                break;
            case "2":
                $containerDiv.load("http://www.yahoo.com/index.html");
                break;
            case "3":
                $containerDiv.load("http://www.bing.com/index.html");
                break;
            default:
                $containerDiv.load("");
                break;
        }
        return true;
    });
});

<select id="selectchoice">
    <option>Select a choice</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Making an AJAX request to a third party domain in the manner you are will not work due to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Comment: can add more to this jsfiddle I have created so that I can see the actual problem.http://jsfiddle.net/KbHh7/

Comment: my intent was to open various pages with nvd3.js content via a pull down menu. if this cannot be done with JQuery, then what other options do I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following :

```
// Add iframe in div
<div id = 'get_contentdiv' style="height:400px;width:500px"><iframe width=400px height=400px src="" id="get_content"></iframe></div>
```

JavaScript Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#selectchoice").change(function () {
        var selectedOption = $('#selectchoice :selected').val().trim();
        $containerDiv = $('#get_content');
        $containerDiv.html("");
        switch (selectedOption) {
            case  "1":   
                $containerDiv.attr("src","http://www.google.com");
                break;

            case "2":
                $containerDiv.attr("src","http://www.yahoo.com");
                break;

            case "3":
                $containerDiv.attr("src","http://www.bing.com");
                break;

            default:
                $containerDiv.html("");
                break;
        }
        return true;
    });
});
```

Here is the demo : http://jsfiddle.net/PLuyu/3/

Comment: Is it possible to replace the default to have it load an initial page, rather than a blank iframe?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use XHR for load remote pages.
Try to use iframe object like this :

```
// html
<iframe src="" id="remotesite"></iframe>

// and the script
document.getElementById('remotesite').load = function() {
 // i'm loaded ;)
};
document.getElementById('remotesite').src = 'http://www.google.fr';
```

A fiddle ;)
http://jsfiddle.net/692D2/

Comment: forgive me, but I am not quite sure how to completely implement this solution.

Comment: Is it possible to replace the default to have it load an initial page, rather than a blank iframe?

Comment: Thanks! Works nicely.